# How to address Compatibility Error with ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, utf-8

I have a ruby program that parses a large block of text with a number of regular expressions. The problem I'm having is that anytime the text contains 'special characters' (for example Kuutõbine or Noël) the program throws an `Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)` How do I force the proper encoding?

Comment: How do you _force_ the proper encoding, or how do you _make sure_ the proper encoding is used? Forcing the encoding is usually not what you want. The heart of the issue is, how do you read your large block of text, and what encoding is it in originally?

Comment: @Amadan so the block of text is being read via an API call. So I'm using HTTParty to read it from JSON. and then dumping that text into a local variable.

Answer (score -2):

Your Regex is being "compiled" as ASCII-8BIT.

Just add the encoding declaration at the top of the file where the Regex is declared:

## encoding: utf-8

And you're done. Now, when Ruby is parsing your code, it will assume every literal you use (Regex, String, etc) is specified in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: "incompatible encoding regexp match (**UTF-8 regexp** with ASCII-8BIT string)" - also, starting with Ruby 2.0, Ruby defaults to UTF-8, and this line has no effect on any currently non-obsolete (non-obscure) Ruby. It is the text that is ASCII-8BIT, not the regex.